# Is there a way to get `cabal repl` to set -XOverloadedStrings on startup?

Tags: haskell, cabal

When I use cabal repl I often type `:set -XOverloadedStrings` in the session. Is there a way to turn on this extension automatically using command line flags for `cabal repl` or some config file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `~/.ghci` put:

```
:set -XOverloadedStrings
```

Putting on `~/.ghci` will enable `ghci` to load those specific configuration whenever it is started.